# CanCan, defining abilites with deeply nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have problem with defining abilites when resources are deeply nested. I have these classes: Teacher, Division, Student, Absence and User (Teacher and Student belongs to Devise User model):

```
#Teacher
has_many :divisions

#Division
belongs_to :teacher

#Student
belongs_to :division
has_many :absences

#Absence
belongs_to :student
```

There is no problem when I want to ensure that Teacher can manage only Students that belongs to his division:

```
#This works
if user.teacher?
  can :manage, Student, division: { teacher_id: user.teacher.id }
end
```

Problem occurrs when I want to ensure that Teacher can manage Absences that belongs to Students from his divisions:

```
#This doesn't work and returns PG::Error: ERROR: column students.divisions does not exist
can :manage, Absence, student: { division: { teacher_id: user.teacher.id } }
```

Any suggestions for defining ability for this nested resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
if user.teacher?
  can :manage, Absence do |absence|
    absence.student.division.teacher_id == user.teacher.id
  end
end
```

The cancan wiki: [Defining Abilities with Blocks](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks)

Comment: I was hoping I could solve it without using blocks. I guess not.